# UICollection View - Dont adds new custom cells

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView inside a view. I did setup hte datasource, the delegate and everything.

This cell is working:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionAddedMembers dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifierAdded forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [colores objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(6)];
    return cell;
}
```

But on my custom cell AddedMemberCollectionViewCell it dont adds new cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AddedMemberCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionAddedMembers dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifierAdded forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *firstSection = [selectedMembersData objectAtIndex:0];
    SelectedContacto *cellData = [firstSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableDictionary *dataForConfigure = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dataForConfigure setObject:cellData.contactAvatar forKey:@"contactAvatar"];
    [dataForConfigure setObject:cellData.contactName forKey:@"contactName"];
    [dataForConfigure setObject:cellData.memberId forKey:@"contactName"];
    [cell configure:dataForConfigure];
    return cell;
}
```

This is the code of the custom cell.

.h file:

```
@interface AddedMemberCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatar;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *memberName;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *removeMember;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *memberId;
- (void) configure:(NSDictionary*)cellData;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "AddedMemberCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation AddedMemberCollectionViewCell
- (void) configure:(NSDictionary*)cellData {
    self.avatar = [cellData objectForKey:@"contactAvatar"];
    self.memberName = [cellData objectForKey:@"contactName"];
    self.memberId = [cellData objectForKey:@"memberId"];
}
@end
```

I could provide more code, but I am thinking would not be necessary. What is happening here?

EDIT:

Registering in viewDidLoad:

```
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionAddedMembers.dataSource = self;
self.collectionAddedMembers.delegate = self;
[self.collectionAddedMembers registerClass:AddedMemberCollectionViewCell.class forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifierAdded];
```

Comment: What does "it dont adds new cells" mean, precisely? Also, show us how you're registering your `AddedMemberCollectionViewCell` with the collection view.

Comment: It means the when I call `[self.collectionAddedMembers reloadData];` it dont adds the cells to the view. See my edit please.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please tell me for learning for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the cell is not actually added to your collection view?

However, you were not doing it right, as calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` will NOT create `UICollectionViewCell` but re-use an existing cell, hence your initialization code in `init` will never have chance to be called.

A good approach should look like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Call custom cell's configure function to init cell content
    [cell configure:cellData];
    return cell;
}

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
-(void)configure:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end

@implementation CustomCell

-(void)configure:(NSDictionary *)data {
    // Init your cell content
}

@end
```

Comment: NSLogs shows `Elements in array: 1 | Cells: 0` calling `self.collectionAddedMembers.visibleCells.count`. I implemented your approach with the same result. Maybe the cells are being added, but they are not visible.